# Listening for a click anywhere on the page without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown menu which toggles on click, and I've gotten rid of jQuery completely so that I can toggle the menu using just AngularJS. The problem is that if the dropdown section is visible, then you have to click the button again to hide it. So the only way to toggle the menu is to use the button right now, and I want users to be able to close the menu by simply clicking somewhere on the page that isn't the menu.

So here's my code right now:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-nav dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" ng-click="showMenu = !showMenu">
    {{ getNavTitle() | translate }} <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-class="{ show: showMenu === true }">
    <li>
        <a id="hottest" ng-click="nav.replaceTo('/one')" ng-class="{active: subnav === 'top'}"><big>{{ 'subnav-one' | translate }}</big></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="latest" ng-click="nav.replaceTo('/two')" ng-class="{active: subnav === 'latest'}"><big>{{ 'subnav-two' | translate }}</big></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="friends" ng-click="nav.replaceTo('/three')" ng-class="{active: subnav === 'fans'}"><big>{{ 'subnav-three' | translate }}</big></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.showMenu = false;
```

So this works. With jQuery I would just listen for a tap somewhere on the page which wasn't one of the three drop down links and the toggle button, and close the menu. But with AngularJS, I'm unsure how to go about doing that.

Comment: coudn't you use a `div` instead of a button for the page?

Comment: [Click in BODY](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2422-capturing-document-click-events-with-angularjs.htm). `<body bn-document-click="showMenu = false">` try. But it can do some unwanted results..

Comment: What kind of effects?

Comment: @Ba5t14n Sorry, I don't know what you mean? The button is just a button, it isn't my entire page...?

Comment: Why have you tagged the question jquery if you don't want to use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using bootstrap. You could use angular-bootstrap or the bootstrap.js itself. I think the auto close feature should already be implemented there.

If you wanna implement it yourself add a click event handler, which closes the menu, to the body with 'once', so the handler will be executed once and then removed from the event listeners.

Comment: Well, I wanted to try and use only Angular for this little example so I was not dependent on any external libraries.

Comment: Angular depends on jquery or it's own jquery-lite. The angular to use it is angular.element ('body'), which returns a jquery object.

Comment: Hm, ok. Would you care to show an example? The reason I made this post is that I'm not sure how to add this click event handler to angular body as you mentioned.

Comment: Check the implementation of angular-bootstrap: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js

Comment: I have already looked through these docs, I'm not exactly all that experienced with AngularJS hence why I'm asking for some help.

Comment: here's a small example. Hope this helps... http://plnkr.co/edit/A1ypuAnzyou7XWjvplXH?p=preview